# How can i fix "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'on')"

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So yesterday I managed to make my discord bot work, and today, it suddenly stopped working due to:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'on')"
    at play (.../include/play.js:85:28)
    at Object.execute (.../Music/play.js:192:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I should mention it is a music bot.

This is the code of the first file mentioned above (include/play.js):

```
      const ytdl = require("discord-ytdl-core");
      const { canModifyQueue } = require("../util/nkm");
      const { Client, Collection, MessageEmbed, splitMessage, escapeMarkdown,MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js");
      const { attentionembed } = require("../util/attentionembed"); 
      const createBar = require("string-progressbar");
      const lyricsFinder = require("lyrics-finder");
      const {
        approveemoji,
        denyemoji,
        BOTNAME,
      } = require(`../config.json`);

/.../
          try {
            if (song.url.includes("youtube.com")) {
               stream = ytdl(song.url, {
                filter: "audioonly",
                opusEncoded: true,
                encoderArgs:encoderArgstoset,
                bitrate: 320,
                seek: seekTime, 
                quality: "highestaudio",
                liveBuffer: 40000,
                highWaterMark: 1 << 25, 

            });
            } else if (song.url.includes(".mp3") || song.url.includes("baseradiode")) {
              stream = song.url;
              isnotayoutube = true;
            }
          } catch (error) {
            if (queue) {
              queue.songs.shift();
              module.exports.play(queue.songs[0], message);
            }

            console.error(error);
            return attentionembed(message, `Error: ${error.message ? error.message : error}`);
          }

          queue.connection.on("disconnect", () => message.client.queue.delete(message.guild.id));

          if(isnotayoutube){
            console.log("TEST")
            const dispatcher = queue.connection
            .play(stream)
            .on("finish", () => {
              if (collector && !collector.ended) collector.stop();

              if (queue.loop) {
                let lastSong = queue.songs.shift();
                queue.songs.push(lastSong);
                module.exports.play(queue.songs[0], message);
              } else {
                queue.songs.shift();
                module.exports.play(queue.songs[0], message);
              }
          })
          .on("error", (err) => {
            console.error(err);
            queue.songs.shift();
            module.exports.play(queue.songs[0], message);
          });
```

the "queue.connection.on("disconnect")" line is the one that gives me the error

What I tried is reverting the package.json because that is the only thing I had changed before the problem, due to some errors I had with something else, I reverted it, and it gave me the same error, meaning it changed nothing. I'd appreciate a fix or atleast explain what makes the code break?

I also tried changing node versions, same thing. I tried deleting the node_modules folder, same thing

(Using node v16)

Comment: `queue` is not defined in your code.